# itext "The document is not open" error on webservice deployed in tomcat 7

Tags: multithreading, web-services, tomcat, itext

I have a jaxws webservice deployed in tomcat, it happens to work well when it services only one request, However when there are two simoultaneous requests process of creating PDF fails with error 
"The document is not open"
The itext jar is contained in the webservice war so We think it is not a classloading problem.
What could be failing?

**EDIT** Code originally provided as an answer:

```
public Boolean PDF(BeanGeneral general2, String carpeta) {
    general = general2;
    document = new Document();
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

    try {
        fileName = carpeta + "/" + general.getNoSAP() + ".pdf";

        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        document.open();
        cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfReader reader = null;
        reader = new PdfReader(general.getParametros().getProperty("images") + "/template.pdf");

        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
        document.newPage();
        cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        getHeader();

        getDetalle();

        getFooter();
        document.close();           
        file = new File(fileName);
    } catch (IllegalPdfSyntaxException e) {        
        error = false;
        return error;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        error=false;
        return error;
    }

    return error;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code. It sounds like your code does not properly take multi threading into account.

Answer (score 1):

Your additional information (which you unfortunately gave as an answer, not an edit of the question) show that the variables `document`, `writer`, and `cb` (and probably even more) actually are not method variables but members of the class instance.

During *simoultaneous requests* this class instance is used by both requests. Thus, both requests put their `Document`, `PdfWriter`, and `PdfContentByte` into the same variables.

This means that the values of the request which is minutely behind win and both requests work using that later request's values. This in turn means that:

- the document which won retrieves all the content generated in the course of both requests from the overwriting of the variable contents onwards; and that
- the document which won is used by the later request even after being closed by the first: this causes the “The document is not open” errors you observed.

*(Actually that is a simplification; as you introduced no memory synchronization barriers, the variables might be buffered in different buffers and synchronization of these buffers may occur at any random time...)*

You can solve this in a number of differing ways:

- declare your method `PDF` as `synchronized`; as the values of the member variables is only required to remain the same during the run of this method, this should suffice:

  ```
  public synchronized Boolean PDF(BeanGeneral general2, String carpeta)
  ```

  or
- turn these member variables into method variables and add them as parameters to the methods `getHeader`, `getDetalle`, and `getFooter` if needed there; or
- turn those member variables into `ThreadLocal` variables.

Comment: My apologies, i've seen your answer and it makes a lot of sense, I really appreciate your help. let me implement it and I let you know. regards